# SQL Server : Select in Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have something like this:

```
Select
    sum(spareparts), 
    month(calculationdate) 
from 
    cz_axnmrs_calculations 
where 
    CASE_ID in (select case_id 
                from cz_axnmrs_cases 
                where insurer_memberid = 'MM-O-5B57274F') 
    and YEAR(calculationdate)='2014'  
group by 
    month(calculationdate) DESC
```

It's cool but i need to edit it a bit more specific. Right it get data from all spareparts, and I need to get it just from LAST ONE! So instead of that to count 3 results via SUM just display LAST one

I try write one more select to sum brackets but it finish with error SQL syntax. Can somebody help me to write this statement?

Thanks

Comment: can you show some sample data??

Comment: Result of: `Select sum(spareparts), month(calculationdate) from cz_axnmrs_calculations where CASE_ID in (select case_id from cz_axnmrs_cases where insurer_memberid = 'MM-O-5B57274F') and YEAR(calculationdate)='2014'  group by month(calculationdate)`

IS:
http://www.upnito.sk/0/3f3rn6taqbg6rs29p8wj634jbwrykg5b.png

Comment: Did you get this resolved?  What is it that you want to see from this result?

Comment: I did it other way @paqogomez, but to learn something more i would be happy if you can give me some info about it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding TOP 1 to the first SELECT

Answer (score 0):

if you mean last one from the result you already got then-

```
SELECT TOP 1
    sum(spareparts), 
    month(calculationdate) 
from 
    cz_axnmrs_calculations 
where 
    CASE_ID in (select case_id 
                from cz_axnmrs_cases 
                where insurer_memberid = 'MM-O-5B57274F') 
    and YEAR(calculationdate)='2014'  
group by 
    month(calculationdate) 
ORDER month(calculationdate) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
SELECT TOP 1
    sum(spareparts), 
    month(calculationdate) 
FROM
    cz_axnmrs_calculations 
WHERE
    CASE_ID in (select case_id 
                from cz_axnmrs_cases 
                where insurer_memberid = 'MM-O-5B57274F') 
    and YEAR(calculationdate)='2014'  
GROU BVY 
    month(calculationdate) DESC
```

Or add another vale to the group by.... Memberid

Answer (score 0):

If showing last row is what you want to do you can try these:

Use `Order by <column> desc` and then pick the 1st row using `Top 1`.

You can also use `ROW_NUMBER()`